# Extending nested array property of an Interface, after .find doesn't work without another "as"

Tags: typescript

I have an interface for a competition object (they are bigger, but reduced here for simplicity):

```
export interface ICompetition {
  players: ICompetitionPlayer[]; 
  state: string;
  ownerId: string;
  duration: number;
}

export interface ICompetitionPlayer {
  id: string; 
  stats: IGame["stats"]; 
}

export interface IGame {  
  stats: Omit<IGameStats, "score" | "rank">; 
}

export interface IGameStats {
  primary: number;
  secondary: number;
  tertiary: number;
  quaternary: number;
  score: number;
  rank: number;
}
```

So in this state, `score` and `rank` are omitted, because mostly they are not needed for that particular interface, however I do have one case where I need them for a function, the function takes in two arguments

```
const doSomething = (playerId: string, competitionData: ICompetition)
```

The problem is that this function DOES need the `score` and `rank` to be present in the stats object, so what I have tried is the following:

```
const doSomething = (playerId: string, competitionData: ICompetition & { players: { stats: IGameStats }[] })
```

Inside the function if I try to log the stats:

```
const doSomething = (playerId: string, competitionData: ICompetition & { players: { stats: IGameStats }[] }) => {
  console.log(competitionData.players[0].stats.rank)
}
```

That works perfectly fine, typescript does not throw any errors and I can see both `rank` and `score` in the autocomplete.

However, if instead I first try to find the player and then log, `rank` and `score` are undefined, for some reason it falls back to the Omitted version

```
const doSomething = (playerId: string, competitionData: ICompetition & { players: { stats: IGameStats }[] }) => {
  console.log(competitionData.players[0].stats.rank); // works

  const player = competitionData.players.find((player) => player.id === playerId)

  // here I have a return/error statement if player was not found

  const playerStats = player.stats;

  console.log(playerStats.rank); // rank here does not exist (according to Typescript)
}
```

Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQGEIBbMYGBSiJOAbwCg44wAbTATzQGcAuA4mQpUENAArsuUANoBdANxwmcbjEyp+qqMgDm85RADuSNPgAmmmNqR7lZgK5R1opPyT2SAIzT6AvgwZQSFhEFDQsXAFSckpqJAlONHplBAsVK11FZVV1PgIAcUwSYGkAIhyYblKFJX9A8Gh4ZFQMHDx8QuL6Zmy1Sv4AeRIqAB4OouAAZT7uABo4cuxoYFK4AB8FpyQAa1KAPiy6oMbQloj2zqmZ5OYwbRJMKA43D28ofWZuYCWkM0fnuDuLw+ZQtSj-F7A97KACO9nUaCQEMBrxBnyWUGAkLeHzgW222JBdR+qjgZggk1IFAAFro4ABeOAACjYiSg5ks1h08yWQliLgAIupMPwiNFhHE4AAybqsqR5OjpXKiy7TXJwXxyDUASgZexucBJEFYwAAdKwIDombyYiIaEK1Ka5TxpAAGWSmircU347WKAD0-rghmg224AWYJPgzqgDMN4v59uFTskPFN6GQZiZLNTUF19P1MdNqQZ9MZMfM2ojcEDcGpaHadcwADc8Jg8RRHEh-WgoNAlahiihEOgWLng5huICIPB0BB7L8UqOmQBCGO6zEwLv6ZRRsdstWVONFr07yM0bjGs0Wq0xw-e30BoP4usNxBThdmYAZkxmZk4DEzDpGAIDgAAVDhyG4bBtDAGAq18IA

Full code to copy/paste if playground link doesnt work:

```
export interface ICompetition {
  players: ICompetitionPlayer[]; 
  state: string;
  ownerId: string;
  duration: number;
}

export interface ICompetitionPlayer {
  id: string; 
  stats: IGame["stats"]; 
}

export interface IGame {
  stats: Omit<IGameStats, "score" | "rank">; 
}

export interface IGameStats {
  primary: number;
  secondary: number;
  tertiary: number;
  quaternary: number;
  score: number;
  rank: number;
}

const doSomething = (playerId: string, competitionData: ICompetition & { players: { stats: IGameStats }[] }) => {
  console.log(competitionData.players[0].stats.rank); // works

  const player = competitionData.players.find((player) => player.id === playerId)

  // here I have a return/error statement if player was not found
  if (!player) return;

  const playerStats = player.stats;

  console.log(playerStats.rank); // rank here does not exist (according to Typescript)
}
```

Comment: The problem is that your `players` property is an intersection of array types which is not identical to an array of intersections.  (`A[] & B[]` behaves differently from `(A & B)[]`, especially with respect to methods like `find()` which end up becoming *overloads*).  I'd suggest changing your `competitionData` type to push the merging down into the property where it belongs, possibly by just defining some new interfaces, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbQZ3N).  Does that address your question fully? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz that is what I ended up doing after I could not find an answer, I was looking for something I can do inline, but couldnt find it

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of two functions or methods behaves like an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function or method, with *multiple call signatures* resolved in the same order as they appear in the intersection:

```
declare let ovldFn: {
  (s: string): number;
  (n: number): boolean;
}

declare let intersectFn: {
  (s: string): number
} & {
  (n: number): boolean
};

ovldFn = intersectFn; // okay
intersectFn = ovldFn; // okay

declare let ovldMthd: {
  m(s: string): number;
  m(n: number): boolean;
}

declare let intersectMthd: {
  m(s: string): number
} & {
  m(n: number): boolean
};

ovldMthd = intersectMthd; // okay
intersectMthd = ovldMthd; // okay
```

One thing TypeScript does *not* do is merge the intersected functions into a single call signature that accepts a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of arguments.  This has been requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107) but so far it has not been implemented:

```
ovldFn(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "abc" : 123); // error!
// no overload matches this call
```

This order-dependent overload resolution of multiple distinct call signatures means that intersections propagating down into objects with function or method properties might behave differently from how you expect them to.

---

Let's look at your original `competitionData` parameter:

```
competitionData: ICompetition & { players: { stats: IGameStats }[] }
```

What goes wrong when you call `competitionData.players.find()`?  Well, we can propagate the intersection down to get the type of `competitionData.players` as `ICompetitionPlayer[] & { stats: IGameStats }[]`.  And propagate down again to get the type of `competitionData.players.find` as something like:

```
{
  ( cb: (v: ICompetitionPlayer) => unknown): ICompetitionPlayer | undefined 
} & {
  ( cb: (v: { stats: IGameStats }) => unknown): { stats: IGameStats } | undefined 
}
```

And *that* is an overloaded method with two distinct call signatures. (Actually `find()`'s [typings](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/a7d10f15bbd28166b869ae00482214e360891613/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L31-L32) are already overloaded with two call signatures, so you actually get *four* call signatures with the intersection.)

So the call to `find((player) => player.id === playerId)` will resolve to the earliest matching overload.  Since you didn't annotate `player`, the compiler will just match it the first overload, which returns an `ICompetitionPlayer | undefined`.

And you're unhappy, because now `player.stats` is not going to have a known `rank` property.

---

I'd say the way to fix this is not to use an intersection at all.  There might be ways around this that still use intersections, but the cleanest conceptual way is to redefine your types so that they form two hierarchies and use interface extension as much as possible to cut down on redundancy.  Perhaps like this:

```
interface IExtendedPlayer extends ICompetitionPlayer {
  stats: IGameStats;
}
interface IExtendedCompetition extends ICompetition {
  players: IExtendedPlayer[]
}

const doSomething = (playerId: string, competitionData: IExtendedCompetition) => {
  console.log(competitionData.players[0].stats.rank);
  const player = competitionData.players.find((player) => player.id === playerId)
  if (!player) return;
  const playerStats = player.stats;
  console.log(playerStats.rank); // okay
}
```

Now `competitionData` has a `players` property of a single array type `IExtendedPlayer[]`, which has a `find()` method that returns an `IExtendedPlayer` whose `stats` property is a `GameStats` with a known `rank` property.  No messy overloads in sight!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5AbgGwCYElgBcIAnKCefAEQjAHskBvAKCSSzIxCOQwnyRsxYAYsABcDZiyQAKKOKj4iAS2ABzAJTjgAVzAAjYgG5JLaWKQ79xTUj00aPEMGMsAvo0lt4HLkh58VQhIyfBFxJikZOSQFZTUbSwMiSVckADIJSLMtXSSbOwcIJxTjSQFsESQAXiRA4lJyEUMkAHoW-gBrEABPSTrgxuBq-kEm1vaaLt6y0eBpAFkQfAALADoiJywaMGl1JAAeJAAGVYBWJAB+JAAiED14a6RxAEYAJgBmdWa2pGIiGiIAEJJD9gHQBMQMDQQFgkGAlvBltAkCslFAkPAQBgMB4WF4fNxeCNsPMVlhwiY4bJ5IoVBoclYiC4pDtzIlrOICo5nClcax2JxCQECPUQqTluTMizqTFafEGUkUukpSxWQqObZ7NySnzylhxbCav0GvgDd8JlM+iKBqaycM9Wbxp0eox3IxQJBYAhkChlKopRAAB4wAHCoIAM29SBwAGFtjBeEp8EoaEMIlIYBxuvVxLH44nk6mAApZ4gAbQAusyWAolhAaXFVNX+AB3YDEHCS2J05tYbQbQts3JGXmSIMhohh4iRxDRuNgBPJwclnrEFW1LtypuU2v4aI4ADi4AgZeuu6g1yro5Y49DtWtM+Qh+P6-P4hQYCT+2fkAAyvgligAAaG4oHgAEIEeAAfG4NmADprgAPmZN0b2DO9+kfaMjz-AC93XGBlHhIhunVJkdzIVMsE4UiLGHcjIiCZMaLI5sAEdtDrIhQBI1id3Arg+MiOCOiEpBUIxVMFFYGhf22XhljpYZpEzVciE7Bs6RA8CFwLFNgAoJYQFzedFyTfTlXoJBVOzEhwllQDcxwiB-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-d+QM0T4aQEAEta1BROgABVugTMDlBgfAercV0PA9aA4FnX9tFUVRoEHCQrQjKNofCiz0xYAr91MkrgBO8sr0iXd9u7NRmxoNsO03Rte37JZ9LEiTMLntfYY3yr1zazSD53VW6cgU9z0vFC+Vv2cvNXwfw-F+XmScQJngEpBLW1wRJIT-jPacc9nJJwIkRFi7MkjNgaFRTB7IGK-WIMxXiWCRyRA4lxHitECE4OgWJFgIlr7-wfHPAAooGQgrMsCb0KkGLhWB0Tz3Xrw4BjlP580An-FgACnwcIEate+j0hj8IgAtIRSip5L2spVfc8i1FsB4c9Cs15JL+T4FsOSkBURNxqDnWyGlZSNm0g9CKRlcz6O4Zo-Sr1tGZx4EFGgIVioPzKhVNSUA4oJSSiJL4lJ446PhjUEJyiwkr2qvjex1hhaJNsq1dqKc1LdRDmHCOjUba8BjvEqSCdKpoMKXk88zZ-EQECSFRO-N86pUQa6IAA)